# Primitives, step counting functions and limits versus Prime Number Theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, functions

Let $L(x)=\int_2^x\frac{dt}{l(t)}$ a **real continuos function since is a primitive**, with $l(t)>0$ for all $x\geq 2$ a real continuos function. And let $\pi (x)$ a **real step function**, you can consider that has jumps in a enumerable set, as an infinite subset of positive integers, and we can consider this **as a counting function** for a set of integers. To fix ideas we can assume that have domains in positive reals $2\leq r$. Then you can provide to me **a proof or a counterexample** to my

> **Question.**  Does the asymptotic $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(x)}{L(x)}=1$$ imply that the proportion $$p(x):=\frac{\pi(x)}{x}$$
>   satisfies $$\lim_{x\to\infty}l(x)p(x)=1?$$

**Thanks in advance,** and sorry by my english.

I am looking for useful answer for this Mathematics Stack Exchange, that provide to me new abilities and refresh my mathematics.

**Appendix:** To give context, my thoughts were about the **integral logarithm** $Li(x)=\int_{2}^{x}\frac{dt}{\log t}$,  and $\pi(x)$ the **prime counting function**, related with the *Prime Number Theorem*.

Comment: You are effectively asking if $\frac{\int_0^xf(t){\rm d}t}{xf(x)} \sim 1$ as $x\to\infty$ for every $f = \frac{1}{l}>0$. Not always true. A sufficient criterion when $xf, \int_0^x f \to \infty$ as $x\to\infty$, is (by L'Hôpitals) $\frac{d\log f}{d\log x} \to 0$, i.e. $f$ grows to infinity slower than any power-law.

Comment: Very thanks much @Kibble Now I take notes of your contribution.

Comment: Thanks to you by discuss the problem in general **Kibble.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my restatement
of this problem:

You have
$L(x)
=\int_2^x\frac{dt}{l(t)}
$
where
$l(x)$
is
(I assume,
to match the case of the
prime number theorem),
a positive monotonic increasing
function
such that
$l(x) \to \infty$
and
$L(x) \to \infty$.

You also have a
step function
satisfying
$\pi(x)
=L(x)(1+o(1))
$.

You want to know
if that implies that
$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{l(x)\pi(x)}{x}
=1
$.

This last equality means that
$l(x)\pi(x)
=x(1+o(1))
$.
Since
$\pi(x)
=L(x)(1+o(1))
$,
this is the same as
$l(x)L(x)(1+o(1))
=x(1+o(1))
$
or
$l(x)L(x)
=x(1+o(1))
$.

We have
$l(x)L(x)
=l(x)\int_2^x\frac{dt}{l(t)}
=\int_2^x\frac{l(x)dt}{l(t)}
$
so,
disregarding a $o(x)$ term,
$l(x)L(x)-x
=\int_2^x\frac{l(x)-l(t)}{l(t)}dt
$
and we want to show that
this last integral
is $o(x)$.

This is so if
$l(x)$ is
"slowly varying"
in the sense that,
for any $c> 0$,
there is an
$x(c)$
such that
$(l(x)-l(t))
\lt c\,l(x)
$
for all
$t > x(c)$,
or
$l(t)
\gt l(x)(1-c)
$.
This will ensure that
the integral is $o(x)$.

For $l(x) = \ln(x)$,
we want
$\ln(x(c))
\gt (1-c)\ln(x)
$.
If we try
$x(c) = x^d$
for some $d$,
this becomes
$\ln(x^d)
> (1-c)\ln(x)
$
or $d > 1-c$.
So, this works for $\ln(x)$.

Comment: I am agree that are neccesarly more assumptions to give more sense to my problem. Very thanks much @martycohen . Now I've proved your computations, very thanks much.

Comment: Is a very good explanation with useful computations and claims for this Mathematics Stack Exchange, very thanks much another time, **marty cohen**.